# What is the difference between append and insert when creating new item in an AWS dynamo db table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When creating new item in an AWS dynamo db table, there are 2 options: append and insert.

What is the difference between choosing append or insert?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing an "Append" will change the datatype in a single action, without an error. "Insert" will not change the datatype.

Comment: still very confusing, can you please provide more details? What do you mean datatype?